# How to show the name of the registered user in Entity Framework instead of email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am writing a .NET Core razor pages project. I am using individual identity feature in my project so aster registering I am am able to see the 'Hi and the mail id of registered user' that is shown in the `_Loginpartial.cshtml` page.

It is using `@User.Identity.Name!`

The code line is:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" 
   title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
```

But I want to show the full name instead of Name (Emailid). I created a domain class named `ApplicationUser` which has my other user details, and it extends `IdentityUser`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

I am using navigation.

In my navbar I want the full name after register which is `FullName`. How to show that in login partial page?

I added that domain class with that 4 properties, then I injected it in ApplicationDbcontext class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

after that from package manager console i added that migration..updated the database ....then i did made implementation for Application user class. My Register.cshtml.cs class:--

```
namespace New11.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account 
{
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;

    ////comented the Iemailsender because its causing error.
    // private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    //// added by me for dependency injection;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    
    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        // IEmailSender emailSender,
        ////added by me for constructor for the upper used dependency injection;
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        ApplicationDbContext db)
        
        
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        // _emailSender = emailSender;
        ////added by me for upper used constructor;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _db = db;

    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        //added by me
        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //// var user = new Identityuser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };...I edited it because in Applicationuser class i am putting the name,address,city,postal code.
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            { 
                UserName = Input.Email, 
                Email = Input.Email ,
                FullName = Input.FullName,
                Address = Input.Address,
                City = Input.City,
                PostalCode = Input.PostalCode,
                PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber

            };
            ////after dependency injection we come to after post handler.and in below line they r creating the user.
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                ////added by me if this is successful we want chk if role exits in the detabase.
                ////if admin user doesnot exits we want to creat it.
                ////StaticDetails class SD created by me.
                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.AdminEndUser))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.AdminEndUser));
                }

                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.HrEndUser))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.HrEndUser));
                }

                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.ItEndUser))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.ItEndUser));
                }
                if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(StaticDetails.EmployeeEndUser))
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(StaticDetails.EmployeeEndUser));
                }

                ////roles are created now have to assign it to a user.
                ////adminuser for now.means when i will creat it will by default take adminuser.
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, StaticDetails.EmployeeEndUser);


                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

               // await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                 //   $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

and I added AddIdentity in place of AddDefaultIdentity the part is:-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

This is my folder structure as of now:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the problem with `ApplicationUser` does it have data? I don't really understand what the `ApplicationUser` class has to do with your problem. You have created it but have you implemented it? Please clarify your problem

Comment: actually i created it to add that 4 extra field in my register page with default fields provided by entity Identity framework...and i implemented it in  Register.cshtml.cs and in ApplicationDbContext.I mentioned that because i want that FullName to show.

Comment: I understand that but we are unable to see if you have succesfully filled the `ApplicationUser` properties. If you have made sure the FullName is filled before you access `ApplicationUser` in your page, there shouldnt be any issue using it in your code. You can just pass it to the view using `@model ApplicationUser` and then passing it on the pages get request. If you already have a `View` class you can add string FullName to it and add the fullname to the view class

Comment: @rbdeenk I explained and updated everything regarding ApplicationUser can you check once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't access the `FullName` property in your HTML page is because you are using a different class to display it. In the return of your post you should return a filled in object of type `ApplicationUser` this will be user in your case.

```
return Redirect(returnUrl, user);
```

To make sure your view interprets your model you define it as the pages model. Or if you already have a class as the pages' model, you add it to that model.

In the case you don't have a model, add this to the top of the page.

```
@model ApplicationUser
```

you can now access the data from the `ApplicationUser` class using `@Model.FullName` Capitalization is very important here.

Comment: sir can you be specific plzz in which class i have to return that (filled with ApplicationUser  object type).

Comment: You have to return Application user on the part where you want to show the user their username so that's somewhere in your OnPost where you do this: "I am am able to see the 'Hi and the mail id of registered user' that is shown in the _Loginpartial.cshtml page."

Answer (score 0):

> So in my navbar I want the full name after register which is FullName
> so how to show that in login partial page.

You also can use the AspNetUsers's username to set your fullname .

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager//ApplicationUser or IdentityUser depends on how you registered in ConfigureServices
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
    </li>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: sir, its still showing me the email id of that user not the name. Actually sir i added that model class for adding that extra 4 values while registration.i configured that class in Register.cshtml.cs

Comment: How did you implement the Class, you are being vague. I feel like you haven't properly implemented the class you are referring to. Could you please update your question with how you implement the class instead of just the class.

Comment: @rbdeenk sir i added everything can you check now please .yess maybe i am being vague. I  am noob in .net core .Btw thanks a lot for all your effort.